# NHibernate TransientObjectException on SaveOrUpdate in multithread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, nhibernate

My application receives frequent remote events through a socket connection, each starting a new thread, and the subsequent actions often triggers the same object graph to be saved each time, with a single locked static session. But while that save executes, new updates are sometimes received which will add new elements to the same object graph. Which I believe is the reason for the exception:

```
TransientObjectException
object references an unsaved transient instance - 
save the transient instance before flushing.
```

If that's the reason, it's understandable. But how I prevent this exception? If I let transaction Rollback, subsequent exceptions occur like StaleStateObject, then NonUniqueObjectException.

So how can this be handled or prevented?

Comment: Check this out please, http://www.bitsandpix.com/entry/hibernate-error-transientobjectexception-object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save-the-transient-instance-before-flushing/ looks like you have mapping issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Likely cause if this exception was that the entity collection was being modified while iterating over the collection during SaveOrUpdate (in different thread). So I believe locks must be placed to avoid these concurrent actions.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to prevent the error:

- `Save()` the newly created referenced objects manually
- Setup appropriate `cascade` settings for the relationships, so the above happens automatically (I personally prefer this)

Of course, it's entirely possible that you are creating a new object when you intended to reference an existing one, or that there's a threading issue even with the lock.

Comment: So do you suggest my assumption is wrong? My thought was that probably one thread is adding an object to the object graph, WHILE another is already in the process of performing a SaveOrUpdate. Wouldn't that produce a TransientObjectException? And wouldn't I then be 100% forced to do a rollback?  I believe my cascades are ok, I exclusively use Cascade.SaveOrUpdate or .Cascade.All on all HasMany relationships.

Comment: If that is a possibility, then you are not synchronizing access correctly. I'd have to see more of your code, but sharing the session between threads is almost never a good idea.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "synchronizing access"? If I have a thread that may add elements to an object graph that another thread may be in the process of persisting, do I need to acquire lock on both the entity update and the persistence?

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I have the same entity-graph-instance saved by different threads/sessions. From what I think I've understood now; this requires a shared lock on persistence as well as on adding entity-elements (to collections in the graph).. Isn't that correct?

Comment: The session is not thread safe, period. If two threads do stuff on the session at the same time, there will be problems, regardless of what they are doing. From what I've seen in your other questions, your current approach is not a good fit for the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Appreciated! Yes I've learned a bit the last days. Still this attempt used lock(session) on any transaction, but that was probably not clear, although I wrote "locked". And that should render it thread safe, I still dare to suggest.. Though the TrancientObjectException here I'm quite positive is simply due to entity graph  being modified while other thread is persisting it to database. Hence not a session-management mistake. That's why I tried to understand if locks are required to avoid that. Which (today) I'm quite sure it is required..